# I cannot determine if this graph is planar. I have tried all tests but cannot see

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am working with a professor on a research paper and we believe this graph is a counter example to our work, but we need to be sure. We cannot determine if this graph is planar and we need to for our research.

[image]
If you are able to see a subdivision of a K5 or a K3,3 as a subgraph of the image, then it is non planar, but we cannot find one, but we also cannot make it planar... please help.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNPTL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph is not planar. There is a $K_5$ configuration.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Merge all the vertices that have not been labelled into one vertex, call it $5$ then $1,2,3,4,5$ will be a graph isomorphic to $K_5$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, just a long list of comments.)

Wiki article on planarity testing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing Since this is for research, I would recommend sitting down with an algorithm and implementing it.

Or, I would put it in a program like Sage, it probably has a method to find if the graph is planar. Here was a link I found: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/schnyder.html
whether it has a subdivision (etc. etc.) should be able to be seen by computation.